# PL/SQL How to compare two associative array?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I check if two associative arrays are same or not?
E.g.

```
ARRAY1('ID') := 1;
ARRAY1('NAME') := 'Joe';

ARRAY2('ID') := 1;
ARRAY2('NAME') := 'Joe';

-- and i want to do like this
IF ARRAY1 = ARRAY2 THEN
   -- Do something.
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare two associative array using a function to compare the keys and values:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE test_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10);
  array1 test_array;
  array2 test_array;
  array3 test_array;

  FUNCTION is_equal(
    arr1 test_array,
    arr2 test_array
  ) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
    i VARCHAR2(10);
  BEGIN
    i := arr1.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      -- Check if the keys in the first array do not exists in the
      -- second array or if the values are different.
      IF    ( NOT arr2.EXISTS( i ) )
         OR ( arr1(i) <> arr2(i) )
         OR ( arr1(i) IS NULL AND arr2(i) IS NOT NULL )
         OR ( arr1(i) IS NOT NULL AND arr2(i) IS NULL )
      THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
      END IF;
      i := arr1.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;

    i := arr2.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      -- Check if there are any keys in the second array that do not
      -- exists in the first array.
      IF    ( NOT arr1.EXISTS( i ) )
      THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
      END IF;
      i := arr2.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN TRUE;
  END;
BEGIN
  array1('ID')   := '1';
  array1('NAME') := 'Joe';

  array2('ID')   := '1';
  array2('NAME') := 'Joe';

  array3('ID')   := '1';
  array3('NAME') := 'Joe';
  array3('XYZ')  := 'ABC';

  IF is_equal( array1, array2 ) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1 and 2 are the same' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1 and 2 are different' );
  END IF;

  IF is_equal( array1, array3 ) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1 and 3 are the same' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1 and 3 are different' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
1 and 2 are the same
1 and 3 are different
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle documentation is your friend.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99915

In particular:

*You cannot compare associative array variables to the value NULL or to each other.*

Which means, if you need to compare associative arrays to each other, you have only two choices... check them element by element, for example in a loop (on the elements of one array - and make sure you check to see if they have the same number of elements); or, if you need to do this often, write your own function that compares arrays in that manner, and call it whenever you need to.

Just don't ask why Oracle is not providing a native PL/SQL function for this; you will very likely get no answers.